# If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges and $a_n\geqslant 0$ for every $n$ then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{1/4}n^{-4/5}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

> If $a_n \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{1/4}n^{-4/5}$ converges.

How to prove this?

Comment: There must be some condition on $a_n$? Also the summation index is not $k$.

Comment: If  $a_n = n^{\frac{16}{5}}$, it's not convergent.

Comment: Even if $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is *bounded*, it's not true, as stated, take $a_n=1$.

Comment: @cmi use Gribouillis's hint by finding the right $p,q$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+ \frac{1}{q}=1$ in Holder's inequality..the series you want to test,indeed converges

Comment: Why reopen this? To encourage the OP to post more questions with zero context (as they already did, since)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Use Hölder's inequality for series.

Edit: since this answer was accepted, I think @cmi found the solution, so here
is my version: Hölder's inequality gives

$$\sum _{n = 1}^{\infty } {a}_{n}^{\frac{1}{4}} \frac{1}{{n}^{\frac{4}{5}}}  \leqslant  {\left(\sum _{n = 1}^{\infty } {\left({a}_{n}^{\frac{1}{4}}\right)}^{p}\right)}^{\frac{1}{p}} {\left(\sum _{n = 1}^{\infty } {\left(\frac{1}{{n}^{\frac{4}{5}}}\right)}^{q}\right)}^{\frac{1}{q}}$$

when $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$ and $p , q  \geqslant  1$. We choose $p = 4$ and
$q = \frac{4}{3}$. It gives

$$\sum _{n = 1}^{\infty } {a}_{n}^{\frac{1}{4}} \frac{1}{{n}^{\frac{4}{5}}}  \leqslant  {\left(\sum _{n = 1}^{\infty } {a}_{n}\right)}^{\frac{1}{4}} {\left(\sum _{n = 1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{{n}^{\frac{16}{15}}}\right)}^{\frac{3}{4}}$$

Both series on the RHS of this inequality converge, hence the series on the LHS also
converges.

Answer (score 3):

A different, more involved way without Hölder:

Let $N\geq 1$, $\alpha \in (1,\frac 65)$ and note that 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{{a_n}^\frac{1}{4}}{n^\frac{4}{5}}\leq 
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{{a_n}^\frac{1}{4}}{n^\frac{4}{5}}\mathbb{1}_{\large\left\{ \frac{1}{a_n^{1/2}n^{8/5}} < \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}} \right\}} + 
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{{a_n}^\frac{1}{4}}{n^\frac{4}{5}}\mathbb{1}_{\large\left\{ \frac{1}{a_n^{1/2}n^{8/5}} \geq \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}} \right\}}$$

Let's deal with the first summand with Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{{a_n}^\frac{1}{4}}{n^\frac{4}{5}}\mathbb{1}_{\large \left\{ \frac{1}{a_n^{1/2}n^{8/5}} < \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}} \right\}} 
&\leq
\left(\sum_{n=1}^Na_n \mathbb{1}_{\large \left\{ \frac{1}{a_n^{1/2}n^{8/5}} < \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}} \right\}}
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{a_n^{1/2}n^{8/5}} \mathbb{1}_{\large \left\{ \frac{1}{a_n^{1/2}n^{8/5}} < \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}} \right\}}
\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}} \mathbb{1}_{\large \left\{ \frac{1}{a_n^{1/2}n^{8/5}} < \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}} \right\}} \right)^{1/2} \\
&\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}  \right)^{1/2} \\
&\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}  \right)^{1/2}
\end{align}
$$

For the second summand, note that if $\displaystyle \frac{1}{a_n^{1/2}n^{8/5}} \geq \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$, then $\displaystyle \frac{{a_n}^\frac{1}{4}}{n^\frac{4}{5}}\leq \frac{1}{n^{8/5-\alpha/2}}$, so that

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{{a_n}^\frac{1}{4}}{n^\frac{4}{5}}\mathbb{1}_{\large\left\{ \frac{1}{a_n^{1/2}n^{8/5}} \geq \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}} \right\}}\leq \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^{8/5-\alpha/2}} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{8/5-\alpha/2}} $$

The last series converges because $\alpha$ was chosen so that $\alpha <\frac 65$.

Finally, $$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{{a_n}^\frac{1}{4}}{n^\frac{4}{5}} \leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}  \right)^{1/2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{8/5-\alpha/2}}$$ The right-hand side does not depend on $n$, we're done.

Comment: A tour de force proof. Nice job,Legrand !

Comment: @DeepSea this technique definitely comes in handy for this kind of problem, see also this answer to a question I asked some time ago https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1753045/66096

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM can you tell  me about this technique you used in your answer when you have time? It seems very intresting.

Answer (score -4):

This isn't a complete answer, since it requires monotonically of $a_n$
If $a_n$ is **monotonic**, then

Define $$b_n=\frac{a_n^{1/4}}{n^{\frac{4}{5}}}
, c_n=\frac{1}{n^{4/5+{1/4}}}$$

Then by the limit comparison test, define $ L :=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{b_n}{c_n}$, since $c_n$ converges, it is enough to show that $L \ne \infty $, (notice if $L=0$, $b_n$ still converges.)

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{a_n^{1/4}}{n^{\frac{4}{5}}}}{\frac{1}{n^{\frac{4}{5}+\frac{1}{4}}}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n^{\frac{1}{4}}n^{\frac{1}{4}}=\lim_{n\to \infty} (a_nn)^{\frac{1}{4}}=0$$

Since $a_n$ converges, $(a_nn)^C \to 0$ for every $C$, (I will leave this part for you to prove, hint: Cauchy convergence test)

Comment: An interesting variation of the question is given that $a_n$ converges, prove that $\frac{{a_n}^{C_1}}{n^{C_2}}$ is convergence for any $C_1 < C_2$

Comment: To prove the original question, prove that $\sup a_nn < \infty$

Comment: please elaborate..Nothing is clear.@Rab Makh